# Cant install mPDF package using Composer PHP - requires ext-gd

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf, chocolatey

I am trying to install mPDF package and when I run the command `composer require mpdf/mpdf` it displays these errors:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 2
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.2 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Can I just download mPDF and place it in my working repo? Or do I have to use Composer to install it?
I tried to search for this errors and I think the only solution would be to install chocolatey and then use it to install `php7.3.2-gd` , but if there is a better solution please let me know!

Comment: You just need to enable gd. Maybe it is already installed, in which case you only have to make sure it is loaded in php.ini. If it is not installed, look up HOW to install it. It is available for many platforms.

Comment: @ErwinMoller I could only find this extension=gd2  and enabled it, but its still showing the same problem. And btw there is nowhere such as a file php.ini , there is only php.ini-production or php.ini-development

Comment: @ErwinMoller found php.ini (my bad) and enabled gd2 and now it shows this error: "mpdf/mpdf v8.0.2 requires ext-mbstring"